# regex for matching CSS-style rules

Tags: regex

I'm looking to find a regex that allows me to match the contents of CSS-style markup. From the following example, I'm hoping to extract the word: **data**

```
declaration {
    data
}
```

The above case is fairly simple, but I'm also looking to avoid matches where *declaration* appears as part of a longer declaration, like so:

```
declaration2 declaration {
    data
}
```

I'm fairly inexperienced when it comes to regex, but I came up with the following rule:

```
(^|\n|\})\s*?declaration\s*?\{([^\}]*?)\}
```

The logic here being that I was hoping to match the beginning of a line, a line break, or a closing '**}**' bracket to ensure I would only match *declaration* when mentioned in isolation. Unfortunately this approach doesn't seem to work.

I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: What flavor of regex are you using? JavaScript or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why your expression doesn't work. I trimmed it down to:

```
/(?:^|})\s*declaration\s*\{([^}]*)}/
```

and tested it with some fake input in JavaScript and it worked.

Assuming you're also using JavaScript, you can get the data as so:

```
var data = /(?:^|})\s*declaration\s*\{([^}]*)}/.exec()[1]
```

Note that this will only get you the data from the *first* occurrence of `declaration`; to get all of them, you should put this in a loop.